# Diff with sed not working

Tags: regex, sed, diff

I am trying to get difference between two htmls. But if there is an attribute called my-attribute in the string, I want to ignore my-attribute and its value when calculating diff.

I am using diff utility to get differences between files.

The below regex works outside diff.

```
sed -E 's@( my-attribute)="[^"]*" @@g' html1.html
```

html1.html is as follows

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <span my-attribute="8885" >html1</span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But inside diff, If i use the same sed, it is giving me a syntax error

```
bash -c 'diff -y <(sed -E 's@( my-attribute)="[^"]*" @@g' html1.html ) <(sed -E 's@( my-attribute)="[^"]*" @@g' html2.html )'
```

This gives the error :  syntax error near unexpected token `('

Would appreciate any help to get the command correct.

Edit: Adding html2.html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <span my-attribute="123" >html2</span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Inian Have added html2.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few characters need escaping.

```
bash -c "diff -y  <(sed -E 's@( my-attribute)=\"[^\"]*\" @@g' html1.html ) <(sed -E 's@( my-attribute)=\"[^\"]*\" @@g' html2.html )"
```

works for me

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can solve your issue:

```
$ cat html1.html | grep -v my-attribute > /tmp/tmp1
$ cat html2.html | grep -v my-attribute > /tmp/tmp2
$ diff /tmp/tmp1 /tmp/tmp2
```

Comment: My requirement is to ignore the attribute my-attribute and its value- In this case my-attribute="123" and my-attribute="8885". The diff should have only html1 & html2